# Filter by multiple patterns with filter() and str_detect()

Tags: r, stringr, tidyverse, stringi

I would like to filter a dataframe using filter() and str_detect() matching for multiple patterns without multiple str_detect() function calls. In the example below I would like to filter the dataframe `df` to show only rows containing the letters `a` `f` and `o`.

```
df <- data.frame(numbers = 1:52, letters = letters)
df %>%
    filter(
        str_detect(.$letters, "a")|
        str_detect(.$letters, "f")| 
        str_detect(.$letters, "o")
    )
#  numbers letters
#1       1       a
#2       6       f
#3      15       o
#4      27       a
#5      32       f
#6      41       o
```

I have attempted the following

```
df %>%
    filter(
        str_detect(.$letters, c("a", "f", "o"))
     )
#  numbers letters
#1       1       a
#2      15       o
#3      32       f
```

and receive the following error

> Warning message: In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex =
>   opts(pattern)) :   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter
>   object length

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The correct syntax to accomplish this with filter() and str_detect() would be

```
df %>%
  filter(
      str_detect(letters, "a|f|o")
  )
#  numbers letters
#1       1       a
#2       6       f
#3      15       o
#4      27       a
#5      32       f
#6      41       o
```

Comment: Corrected, thank you. Always learning. I have been using case_when() and  became confused

Comment: If this is the correct syntax, it strikes me that `str_detect()` is intended for more limited situations than I had supposed. What function would be recommended if you were looking for partial matching against a longer list of longer strings? Back to `grep`?

Answer (score 1):

To synthesize the accepted answer even further, one could also define a vector with search patterns of interest and concatenate those with `paste` using its `collapse` argument where the search criterion *'or'* is defined as `'|'` and the search criterion *'and'* as `'&'`.

This could be useful, for example, when the search patterns are automatically generated somewhere else in the script or read from a source.

```
#' Changing the column name of the letters column to `lttrs`
#' to avoid confusion with the built-in vector `letters`
df <- data.frame(numbers = 1:52, lttrs = letters)

search_vec <- c('a','f','o')
df %>% 
    filter(str_detect(lttrs, pattern = paste(search_vec, collapse = '|')))

#  numbers letters
#1       1       a
#2       6       f
#3      15       o
#4      27       a
#5      32       f
#6      41       o
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this possible with an "&" rather an "|" (sorry dont have enough rep for comment)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33089656)